# Can rsync copy all files (including special ones like soft and hard links) from a ntfs partition to another one?

Tags: rsync, backup, file-copy, ntfs, ntfs-3g

To make backups for my computer, I installed Xubuntu on an external hard disk to boot from and create images in another partition on the external hard disk. This also ensures that the file systems of the system to be backed up are not mounted during the backup.

To create *images* of the ntfs Windows system and of the ntfs home partition of my computer I use `ntfsclone`. For *images* of ext4 partitions I use `fsarchiver`. The packages `libntfs-3g883` and `ntfs-3g` are installed on my system in order to deal with ntfs partitions.

It is quite useful to have not only an image, but also *snapshots of copies* of the file systems. I have written scripts that essentially execute these commands:

```
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sdaX /mnt/alt     # X varies for the partitions to be backed up
DATE=$(\date -Idate)
mkdir /backup/X_${DATE}
sudo rsync --stats --numeric-ids --quiet -axAhHP  /mnt/ /backup/X_${DATE}   # the / after mnt matters!
sudo rsync --stats --numeric-ids --quiet -axAhHPc  /mnt/ /backup/X_${DATE}
sudo umount /mnt
```

These scripts work fine for fat, vfat and ext4 partitions, but they fail with thousands of error messages for the ntfs Windows 10 system partition, even when I use a ntfs partition as destination (which seems to be necessary since Windows ACLs and their Linux counterparts in ext4-partitions differ).

Googling around, I found articles that Windows soft and hard links could be the culprit. There are Linux recovery systems that can handle all kinds of partitions and all kinds of files in them, including Windows ones: How do they access the files and how do they do it so that they also copy link files and ACLs 1:1?

**What is the right way to copy all ntfs files of a partition such that they can be used by a Windows system like the original files?**